# Inserting selected RadioButton in SQLite DB using eclipse

Tags: android

Can anyone get me complete android code for java activity which uses RadioGroup and then insert the selected RadioButton in SQLite Database?
These are my xml and java files:

signupform.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="Sign Up Form" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Username" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginLeft="21dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Password" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:inputType="textPassword" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="E-mail Address" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="14dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"></EditText>
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView5" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio0" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Investor" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Root level Worker"></RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Sign Up" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginTop="34dp"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup1"></Button>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Type of User" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText3" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="14dp"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Signup.java

```
package com.RootLevelFinanceApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.Data;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Signup extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button signup;
Button cancel;
EditText username;
EditText password;
EditText email;
RadioGroup rg;

DataHelp d = new DataHelp(Signup.this);;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signupform);

    signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    signup.setOnClickListener(this);

    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button2:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(Signup.this, Loginoptions.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.button1:
            username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

            String usrnm = username.getText().toString();
            String pswrd = password.getText().toString();
            String eml = email.getText().toString();

            boolean invalid = false;

            if(usrnm.equals("")){
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(pswrd.equals("")){
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(eml.equals("")){
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ID Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(invalid == false){
                addEntry(usrnm, pswrd, eml);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i2 = new Intent(Signup.this, Loginoptions.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                finish();
            }

            break;
    }
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    d.close();
}

public void addEntry(String usrnm, String pswrd, String eml){

    SQLiteDatabase db = d.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("username", usrnm);
    values.put("password", pswrd);
    values.put("email", eml);

    try{
        db.insert(DataHelp.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

DataHelp.java

```
package com.RootLevelFinanceApp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class DataHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "rlf.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "login";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL);";

public DataHelp(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        System.out.println("In onCreate");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //String s1 = "Create table " + SIGNUP + "( " + ID + " integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT , "+ USERNAME +" text ,"+ PASSWORD +" text, "+ EMAIL +" text)";
    //db.execSQL(s1);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: what does eclipse have to do with that?

Comment: I am creating my project using eclipse.
I want to get code for inserting selected RadioButton from group of RadioButtons, and then insert the same in database.

Comment: so show what you wrote so far

Comment: Dude, m new at this website.. dunno how to upload xml & java files..Can u tell me how to do so?

Comment: without showing your code the chanses that you get any answer are weak

Comment: Yes, u r right, but m trying to copy-paste my xml & java codes in comment box, but it shows 'too-long' message. Can u guide me for the same?

Comment: Looking for code to insert selected RadioButton by user.

Comment: for one you need to upgrade you table to add the column for the radio button

Comment: then you need to get the value from the radio and put it in the contentvalues.

Comment: Upgrade table???
Over here in DataHelp.java?

Comment: like this??

private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL, usertype TEXT NOT NULL);";

Comment: @njzk2 How to get value of selected RadioButton?

Comment: read the doc for radiogroup